# Searching text using grepl

Tags: r

I am trying to search character in a string

Below is the code i tried

```
if grepl("<ERRCA0006>",df$t) {
cmnt = "Appfabric"
}
```

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: At first glance, `df$t` should come before the first closing/right parenthesis. Also, change the name `df` to something else to avoid naming conflict in R.

Comment: missing parenthesis..`if (grepl("<ERRCA0006>",df$t))`

Comment: iam getting below error                                                                                       the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: `grepl` returns a >=1 length vector while `if` statement accepts only ==1 length vector.

Comment: Is there any other way to do the above query

Comment: You can wrap your `grepl` statement within the `any` function perhaps

Comment: please don't edit your question to make it into something completely different, especially as you've [asked the same question elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239756/search-string-and-create-variable)

Answer (score 1):

I think the first answer works just fine if you only want to test for any appearance of "" in datf$t. However if you wanted cmnt to test each row in datf, I think you could do this with the ifelse() function.

```
 cmnt <- ifelse(grepl("<ERRCA006>", datf$t), "Appfabric", "NotFabric")
```

Or you could use a for loop.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(datf)) {
    if(grepl("<ERRCA006>", datf$t[i]) {
        cmnt <- "Appfabric" } }
```

Comment: i tried                                                                                                                         cmnt <- ifelse(grepl("<ERRCA006>", datf$t), "Appfabric", "")                                                                                                                                   cmnt <- ifelse(grepl("<ERRCA007>", datf$t), "Appfabric", "")                             the first statement is working fine but second statement is overwriting the first statement when i try running second one

Comment: cmnt should be the same length as datf$t. Are you trying to call it on multiple columns? Maybe something like this is better for your situation: `cmnt_list <- list(); cmnt <- ifelse (); cmnt_list <- c(cmnt_list, cmnt)`

Comment: I have multiple ifelse condition to use.

Comment: Can you show me? I don't really understand how these tests are fitting into your overall mission

Comment: I am using all these in a dataset;                                                               cmnt_list <- list()                                                                                  left$cmnt_list <- ifelse(grepl("ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>",left$text), "Appfabric Error Code ERRCA0006", "")

left$cmnt_list <- ifelse(grepl("ErrorCode<ERRCA0006>:SubStatus<ES0001>",left$text), "Appfabric Error Code ERRCA0012","")                                                                                                                                  I have more tha 50 ifelse

Comment: i have more than 50 ifelse condition to process like this. First ifelse condition  is working fine but not others

Comment: gh<c("ErrorCode<ERRCA0013","ErrorCode<ERRCA0017","ErrorCode<ERRCA0018")
> cmt<-ifelse(grepl("ErrorCode<ERRCA0013",gh), "Code ERRCA0012", "")
> cmt
[1] "Code ERRCA0012" ""               ""              
> cmt<-ifelse(grepl("ErrorCode<ERRCA0017",gh), "Code ERRCA0014", "")
> cmt
[1] ""               "Code ERRCA0014" ""              
> cmt<-ifelse(grepl("ErrorCode<ERRCA0018",gh), "Code ERRCA0015", "")
> cmt
[1] ""               ""               "Code ERRCA0015"

Comment: Ok so are you testing  different dataframes or columns?

Comment: I want the output as for cmt as "Code ERRCA0012" "Code ERRCA0014" "Code ERRCA0015"

Comment: If you want to grab all of the ErrorCodes out a regex capture expression is probably a better way to go about it

Comment: `cmnt <- grep("Error", gh, value = T) cmnt <- gsub("Error\\(Code\\)<\\(ERRCA\\d{4}\\), "\\1\\2", cmnt`

Comment: i have modified the question

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your problem.
It checks if any of the elements in the vector contains the error and assigns cmnt accordingly.

```
if(sum(grepl("<ERRCA0006>",df$t)) > 0){
   cmnt = "Appfabric"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sapply` function instead of loop. Here I give an example of checking `A` character and returning `this is an A` comment. The output is a list, but if needed we can change it into character vector (last line of code)

```
df <- data.frame(t = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T))
cmnt <- sapply(df$t, function(x) if(grepl("A", x)) return("this is an A"))
cmnt <- as.character(cmnt)
```